# Filter next focus components

Tags: java, swing, focus

I want to filter the next focus componenet 
using the tab key

for example , i dont want to focus `JLabel`, `JScrollPane`, `JScrollBar` button, `JPanel`, etc...

How can i do that  dynamically without the programmer to handle the focus?

Here is what i did :

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new JTPCFocusTraversalPolicy());

public class JTPCFocusTraversalPolicy extends LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy {
  protected boolean accept(Component aComponent) {
    return !JTPCGUIUtils.getInstance().filterCompoenent(aComponent);
  }
}
```

I had a case of a `JList` and a `JButton`, but i have to press tab 4 times for moving between thous components.

In my case how can i make only 2 tabs for moving between list and button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Java 1.4 onwards you can define [FocusTraversalPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html).

Comment: found my problem , 
i did write my own FocusTraversalPolicy and looks like it works ,
but i had some hidden panel there with some buttons not visible
sorry and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the examples at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

> The check box was removed from the focus cycle with this line of code:

```
togglePolicy.setFocusable(false);
```